# QFT: strange interaction term?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, field-theory

I have QED plus a massive vector field $A'_{\mu}$. The Lagrangian is:
$$L = L_{QED} -\frac{1}{4} F'^{\mu \nu}F'_{\mu \nu} + \frac{a}{2} F^{\mu \nu}F'_{\mu \nu} -\frac{1}{2}M^2 A'_{\mu}A'^{\mu}+ \textrm{interaction term with fermions}.$$
Now, the first term is the classical kinetic term for a spin-1 particle. But how can I interprete the second term? It is an interaction vertex with only two line? How can I derive the Feynman rule associated to this vertex?

Answer (score 7):

Your fields recombine into linear combinations of themselves.

Define
$$ A_{\mu} = \alpha S_{\mu} + \beta T_{\mu} $$
$$ A'_{\mu} = \gamma T_{\mu} $$

and rewrite $\mathcal{L}$ in terms of $S$ and $T$.

Then require that the coefficients that you get are standard:
$$ \mathcal{L} = - \frac{1}{4} U_{\mu \nu} U^{\mu \nu} - \frac{1}{4} V_{\mu \nu} V^{\mu \nu} + \frac{M_{\text{new}}^2}{2} T_{\mu} T^{\mu}. $$

Here I defined $U_{\mu \nu} = \partial_{[\mu} S_{\nu]}$ and $V_{\mu \nu} = \partial_{[\mu} T_{\nu]}$.

You will end up with three algebraic equations on $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$. Solve them to determine $\alpha(a), \beta(a), \gamma(a)$.

$S$ and $T$ are the true fields of the theory, not $A$ and $A'$. There is no $U_{\mu \nu} V^{\mu \nu}$ term. $S$ is massless Maxwell and $T$ is massive, though the mass $M_{\text{new}}(M, a)$ is different.

Comment: A downvote less than 1 minute after I posted this answer. Maybe the downvoter can explain what is wrong with it?

Comment: I thought so...

Comment: There is an inveterately silent  ritual downvoter around reflexively downvoting several new answers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! In fact there is no mixed term if I redefine the fields as you said. How did you know that this redefinition makes the right job?